# Top navigation menu depending on sidebar

Tags: javascript, menu, navigation, vue.js, vue-router

I am working on a Single Page Application using [VueJS](https://vuejs.org) and [vuerouter](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router).

My App.vue looks like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <header><topbar></topbar></header>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <main><router-view></router-view></main>
      <nav><sidebar></sidebar></nav>
    </div>

    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

I would like to achieve the following behaviour:

- The sidebar menu displays static main categories the user can navigate to
- The topper menu depends on the main sidebar menu and must displays sub-categories related to the main categories.

My first thought is that I can share a common state with vuex. Clicking on a main category on the sidebar would trigger a new CURRENT_STATE that would be read by the top bar. Then there would be a sort of conditional rendering based on the CURRENT_STATE.

But I am pretty sure there is a nicer/cleaner way to achieve this.

Has anyone already encountered this issue ? Any idea is welcomed :)
Thanks !

Comment: Your main Vue knows both the sidebar and the topbar. Your main Vue can control their shared data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up your topbar as such:

```
<header><topbar :key="$route.path"></topbar></header>
```

Any path change should trigger the topbar to refresh. If your sidebar should be static, then you don't have to add a key parameter there so that that won't be refreshed like the topbar will.

Comment: Hi @Joos, thanks. In my case, it also works without passing key as a prop. My topbar component is reacting to $route.path without the prop. I managed to conditionally render the template of the topbar component by checking $route.path . #KeepItSimple :)

Comment: The key property is a nice trick to keep in mind, but if you don't need it that's even better :P nice!